# Complex Integration, Homotopics and Deformation theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm having a bit of confusion here, i think this may be right but if someone could just quickly check it and let me know where I've gone wrong, that would be greatly appreciated

here we go:

Evaluate the following Integrals.

> $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z}$$
>   where $\gamma(t) = cos(t) + 2i sin(t),~t\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

From my understanding then, we can write
$$\gamma_{0}(t) = cos(t) + 2i sin(t)$$
define $\gamma_{1}(t) = 2(cost + sin(t))$
and then show that these two are homotopic via
$H(s,t)=(1-s)\gamma_{0}+s\gamma_{1}$

H(t,0) = $\gamma_{1}$, H(t,1) = $\gamma_{2}$, with $\gamma_1(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \gamma_2(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\gamma_1(\frac{3\pi}{2}) = \gamma_2(\frac{3\pi}{2})$

to show these two paths are homotopic, then via the deformation theorem we have
for any $A \subseteq_{open} \mathbb{C}$ with f analyic on A, if $\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$ are two piecewise smooth curves in A that ar ehomotpic to each other then
$$\int_{\gamma_{1}} f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_{2}}f(z)dz$$
so then for f as defined above we have

$$\int_{cos(t)+2i sin(t)}\frac{dz}{z} = \int_{2(cost+isint)}\frac{dz}{z} = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \frac{i cost+sint}{cost+isint} dt$$
from the contour chain rule
then
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\frac{i cost+sint}{cost+isint} dt = [it]^{3\pi/2}_{\pi/2} = \pi i $$

does this look right? anyone see any holes? thanks in advance.
Sincerely

**edit: to check if the homotopy is with in $\{z \neq 0\}$

so from my understanding all i need to do is make sure that $H(s,t) \neq 0$, $\forall s \in [0,1],t \in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, then the above integral is fine.

Expanding $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ gives $H(s,t) = (1+s) cos(t)+i 2sin(t) \neq 0$

**edit 2: incidentially i just noticed i should have used this homotopoy in the first place....im stupid.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: You need to check that the homotopy is actually inside $\{z\neq0\}$.

Comment: Note that that very same $H$ is a homotopy on $\mathbb{C}$ for any pair of loops, but any pair of loops won't give the same integral of $1/z$. So, a check that that is actually a homotopy in $\{z\neq0\}$ for that particular pair of loops is necessary.

Comment: sorry, i'm a little lost, i understand that for a closed contour 1/z would give us $2\pi$ i, and if i'm understanding right, what you're telling me to check is that H doesn't actually enter the region of z = 0 right? so my job is to check the values of s and t so that the linear combination of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, doesn't equal zero? and this is particularly important in this case because of 1/z being what it is

Comment: That's right. That check is, by the way, one of the hypotheses of the theorem that you are using. That $H$ is a homotopy *inside* the domain where the integrand is analytic, or some other similar wording. You would need to consult your source.

Comment: I've added what i hope answers the question.

Comment: Apologies, i've found apart of the source material i had previously overlooked in my sleep deprived state.